# Bootstrap fonts seem to be striped on Safari iOS

Tags: ios, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a simple application which uses bootstrap version 3.3.5 and a button with a dropdown:

```
<!-- Large button group -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Large button <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you run that on Safari iOS, the `down` icon seems to be cut:

[image]

Is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Are you using a font for those icons, or is that the built in one?

Comment: I used bootstrap class to build that icon and button...

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, that was made by `caret` css class:

```
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px dashed;
  border-top: 4px solid \9;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

The following line I modified, from:

```
  border-top: 4px dashed;
```

to

```
  border-top: 4px solid;
```

and it works fine.